# How to use array values that are dates as XValues on a chart ? (VBA)

Tags: arrays, vba, date, charts

I have a chart on which I graph 2 series from an array.
For each series I try to set the XValues with the first dimension of the array which are dates.

My problem is that the dates shown on the chart X-axis are the 00/01/1990 etc dates, not the dates in my array (I checked those).
How to show the right dates on the chart ?

I do the following:

```
Set ch = ws.Shapes.AddChart(Width:=1000, Height:=500, Left:=ws.Columns("B").Left, Top:=ws.Range("B66").Top).Chart
    With ch
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "TITLE"

        For i = 1 To 2
            Set s = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            With s
                .Values = Application.Index(vD, , i + 1)
                If i = 1 Then
                    .Name = "S1"
                    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
                ElseIf i = 2 Then
                    .AxisGroup = 2
                    .Name = "S2"
                    .ChartType = xlColumnStacked
                End If
                .XValues = ws.Application.Index(vD, , 1)
            End With
        Next i
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).CategoryType = xlTimeScale
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy" 
    End With
```

EDIT: `vD` is a variant in which I have my 3 series the 2 to graph as values and the to graph as XValues (dates).

So vD does look like this:

```
|   1      |   2   |   3  |
|2017-01-01|   12  |  115 |
|2017-01-02|   15  |  101 |
|2017-01-03|   11  |  125 |
|2017-01-04|   12  |  139 |
...
```

Then the first series to be graph is the 2nd column, then the 3rd and each time I add the 1st column of the variant as XValues.

Comment: It's impossible to help you debug with the data you have, please share a sample of your chart's data. Also, what and where is `vD` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the modified code (explanation inside the code comments):

```
Set ch = ws.Shapes.AddChart(Width:=1000, Height:=500, Left:=ws.Columns("B").Left, Top:=ws.Range("B9").Top).Chart
With ch
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.text = "TITLE"

    For i = 1 To 2
        Set s = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With s
            ' ===== THIS IS THE PART I'VE MODIFIED =====
            ' Values in Range "B1:B4" for 1st series, and in Range "C1:C4" for 2nd series
            .Values = "=" & ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, i + 1), ws.Cells(4, i + 1)).Address(True, True, xlA1, xlExternal)
            ' XValues in Range "A1:A4" for both series
            .XValues = "=" & ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(4, 1)).Address(True, True, xlA1, xlExternal)

            If i = 1 Then
                .Name = "S1"
                .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
            ElseIf i = 2 Then
                .AxisGroup = 2
                .Name = "S2"
                .ChartType = xlColumnStacked
            End If                
        End With
    Next i
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).CategoryType = xlTimeScale
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
End With
```

Comment: Thanks but the plan was to graph the `Values` and `XValues` directly from the array `vD` so I don't have to put a lot of data in a range on a sheet. What you did is the same thing as I did except that you take the values from a range on a sheet.

Comment: @Arty but it's working with dates on X-Axis, no ? isn't this what you asked for in your post ?

Comment: No. What I asked for is that the dates are shown on the X-Axis while still using the data directly from the array.

Comment: @Arty I use this method, connecting it directly to a `Range` ( a dynamic Defined `Range), but still using a `Range`).